# SSMS cannot connect remote server by IP through Windows authentication

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms, windows-server, windows-authentication

I'm trying to connect a remote server by `IP,port` via Windows authentication.
It will end out with the following error

> Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while
>   attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This
>   could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was
>   unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting
>   to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=41306;
>   handshake=27677;  (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2)

However, if connect to `IP,port` but login with `sa` through SQL Server authentication then I can connect to the server correctly.

Moreover, if I switch to `MachineName,port` and login via Windows authentication then I can successfully connect too.

Not sure what kind of setting/adjustment I need to make this use case work.

Environment

- My laptop is Win10 and the SQL Server 2012 is on a Windows server 2012 R2
- These two machines are in the same domain.
- We are using another port instead of default 1433.

Case I tried

1. remote `IP,port` via Windows authentication - failed
2. remote `MachineName,port` via Windows authentication - successful
3. remote `IP,port` via SQL Server authentication(sa account) - successful
4. remote `IP\MSSQLSERVER,port` via Windows authentication - failed
5. RDP to remote then use ssms there `IP,port` via Windows authentication - successful

Setting I have tried

- Add the SQL Server exe to the inbound rule
- Launch SQL Server browser
- Change IP1 to the IPv4 I'm using and Active/Enabled it(restart service too)
- Make sure TCP/IP are enabled on Protocols of MSSQLSERVER and Client Protocols(/32bit)
- Add the port I'm using to IPAll/TCP Port and keep Dynamic ports blank

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out the timeout is actually a timeout...
After I expend the connection timeout to 90 sec it connected after about a minute.

Infrastructure guys say this might since it's trying to resolve the machine name or something? (I'm not really familiar with network and setting stuff).
I will update this answer if they figure out any way to speed up the process.

Answer (score 1):

The case number 4 (`IP\MSSQLSERVER,port`) is not necessary. However, the issue seems with security protocols/providers in windows level where SQL Service is running.

Hope [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2015/07/09/an-error-occurred-during-the-pre-login-handshake-dbnetlibconnectionopen-secdoclienthandshake-ssl-security-error-when-connecting-to-sql-server/) would help for further troubleshooting and workaround solution, applying windows security path would be a proper fix such issues.